# Erlang files diff

Tags: file, erlang, diff

I need to get diff of 2 files. For example:

```
File 1:
asd
qwe

File 2:
asd
qwe
zxc
```

I need line `zxc` in my code. How to do it with erlang?

Comment: Are the files sorted by lines?

Comment: this one file, but in time it can change (added lines)

Comment: You might want to compute the MD5 of each file, if the output is identical, then don't bother finding the difference.

Comment: but files are different in the main case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
1> {ok,Bin}=file:read_file("1.txt").
{ok,<<"asd\nqwe\n">>}
2> {ok,Bin2}=file:read_file("2.txt").
{ok,<<"asd\nqwe\nzxc\n">>}
3> L1=binary:split(Bin, <<"\n">>, [global]).   
[<<"asd">>,<<"qwe">>,<<>>]
4> L2=binary:split(Bin2, <<"\n">>, [global]).
[<<"asd">>,<<"qwe">>,<<"zxc">>,<<>>]
5> L2 -- L1.    
[<<"zxc">>]
```

but if you want the other difference in first file you have to do L1 -- L2 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I will handle the problem this way:

```
-module(main).

-export([main/0]).    

read_all(F) ->
    R = file:read_line(F),
    read_all(F, R, []).
read_all(F, {ok, Data}, A) ->
    R = file:read_line(F), 
    read_all(F, R, A ++ [Data]);
read_all(_, eof, A) ->
    A.

main() ->
    {ok, F1} = file:open("file1", [raw, read_ahead]),
    F1Data = read_all(F1),
    {ok, F2} = file:open("file2", [raw, read_ahead]),
    F2Data = read_all(F2),   
    S1 = sets:from_list(F1Data),
    S2 = sets:from_list(F2Data),
    io:format("~p ~p~n", [S1, S2]),
    sets:subtract(S2, S1).
```

You may need to polish it by presenting the result of the set operation (`sets:subtract` in this case)  in a more human readable format.